# Is there any way to "slow down" a for-loop execution in google sheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet script, which will grab same data from the sheet to use it in a server request and save the response back on array, using for-loop, what I faced when using a for loop the server returns this error says "To Many Requests", is there any way which will helps to slow down the loop execution?, I'll attach an example using a fake API.

```
function requestForLoop(){
let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89];
  var result=[];
  
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    
   var val=data[i];
   var url1 ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"+val;
        
   var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1);
   var res = response1.getContentText();
    
    
 var data1 = JSON.parse(res);
 
  

var tatalResult1 = data1.id;
result[i]=tatalResult1;
    
  Logger.log(i+"The result is :"+result[i]);
}

}
```

Comment: `Utilities.sleep`?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detail of API you want to use, when there is the method of batch request in the API, I thought that your issue might be able to be resolved. How about this? If it's no, I also think `Utilities.sleep` will be useful as TheMaster's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Every before your loop ends, as TheMaster and Tanaike mentioned, you can use `Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)`;

Output:

[image: output]

Code Snippet:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var val = data[i];
    var url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + val;

    var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1);
    var res = response1.getContentText();

    var data1 = JSON.parse(res);

    var tatalResult1 = data1.id;
    result[i] = tatalResult1;

    Logger.log(i + " The result is :" + result[i]);
    Utilities.sleep(1000); // parameter in milleseconds (1000 ms = 1 sec)
  }
```

Also, beware as there are quotas for Apps Script. For `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` calls, there is a limit of 20000 per day. You might be wary about this quota.

For other quotas relating to apps script, please see [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).